# fragment back stack issue in build version 25.2.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, build.gradle

I am using fragments in my project, I am facing one issue in recent android build version `25.2.0` that is clearing fragments not working properly.

Let me explain about my issue.

Initially I have added **DbFragmentView()** fragment class without adding it on backStack.

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new DbFragmentView()).commit();
```

For all other fragments I am adding it to backstack Using below methond

```
   @Override
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String Title) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

        if (!fragmentPopped) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, fragment.toString());
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Title);
        }
    }
```

On some cases I needed to clear all my backstack fragments, for that I am using below code

```
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                }
```

Everything worked perfectly before changing build version to `25.2.0`.

But After I changing my build version from `25.1.0` to `25.2.0` the above code clearing all my fragments  and then it goes back to my first **DbFragmentView()** fragment but the view is not appearing.

`onCreateView` method called but View looks transparent so I can see other app that is in background.

Then I again changed my build version to `25.1.0` then it worked as usual.

Can anyone please tell me the solution to fix this issue

**Note** : this issue occurred only in latest build version `25.2.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android updated the support library version recently, I have changed this in my code. Now the issue resolved.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
```